# ffmpeg - convert mxf to ts while maintaining "Text" tracks

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I have a `.mxf` file that has 608/708 captions. When I look at the MediaInfo of this file I see below Text information. My goal is to extract 608/708 captions from this file using ccextractor. To do that first I am converting this to a .ts file using below ffmpeg command as `ffmpeg -i abc.mxf -c:v mpeg2video -s 160x90 -b:v 300k -map 0:v -map 0:d abc.ts`. But when I check the MediaInfo of `abc.ts` file I don't see any of "@type:Text" tracks in the output.

I also tried with `-copy_unknown` but still, I am not able to see "@type:Text" in output .ts file MediaInfo.

Also in some file I see `"MuxingMode": "Ancillary data / CDP"` and some files I am seeing `"MuxingMode": "A/53 / DTVCC Transport"`. What is the difference between these two?

Request you to share your valuable feedback. Thank you.

```
[{
    "@type": "Text",
    "@typeorder": "1",
    "ID": "512-CC1",
    "Format": "EIA-608",
    "MuxingMode": "Ancillary data / CDP",
    "Duration": "2645.142",
    "BitRate_Mode": "CBR",
    "FrameRate": "29.970",
    "FrameCount": "79275",
    "Delay": "0.000",
    "Delay_DropFrame": "Yes",
    "Delay_Source": "Container",
    "StreamSize": "0",
    "extra": {
        "Delay_SDTI": "0",
        "CaptionServiceName": "CC1",
        "CaptionServiceDescriptor_IsPresent": "No",
        "cdp_length_Min": "73",
        "cdp_length_Max": "73"
    }
}, {
    "@type": "Text",
    "@typeorder": "2",
    "ID": "512-1",
    "Format": "EIA-708",
    "MuxingMode": "Ancillary data / CDP",
    "Duration": "2645.142",
    "BitRate_Mode": "CBR",
    "FrameRate": "29.970",
    "FrameCount": "79275",
    "StreamSize": "0",
    "extra": {
        "CaptionServiceName": "1",
        "CaptionServiceDescriptor_IsPresent": "No",
        "cdp_length_Min": "73",
        "cdp_length_Max": "73"
    }
}, {
    "@type": "Text",
    "@typeorder": "3",
    "ID": "512-2",
    "Format": "EIA-708",
    "MuxingMode": "Ancillary data / CDP",
    "Duration": "2645.142",
    "BitRate_Mode": "CBR",
    "FrameRate": "29.970",
    "FrameCount": "79275",
    "StreamSize": "0",
    "extra": {
        "CaptionServiceName": "2",
        "CaptionServiceDescriptor_IsPresent": "No",
        "cdp_length_Min": "73",
        "cdp_length_Max": "73"
    }
}, {
    "@type": "Text",
    "@typeorder": "4",
    "ID": "512-3",
    "Format": "EIA-708",
    "MuxingMode": "Ancillary data / CDP",
    "Duration": "2645.142",
    "BitRate_Mode": "CBR",
    "FrameRate": "29.970",
    "FrameCount": "79275",
    "StreamSize": "0",
    "extra": {
        "CaptionServiceName": "3",
        "CaptionServiceDescriptor_IsPresent": "No",
        "cdp_length_Min": "73",
        "cdp_length_Max": "73"
    }
}, {
    "@type": "Text",
    "@typeorder": "5",
    "ID": "512-4",
    "Format": "EIA-708",
    "MuxingMode": "Ancillary data / CDP",
    "Duration": "2645.142",
    "BitRate_Mode": "CBR",
    "FrameRate": "29.970",
    "FrameCount": "79275",
    "StreamSize": "0",
    "extra": {
        "CaptionServiceName": "4",
        "CaptionServiceDescriptor_IsPresent": "No",
        "cdp_length_Min": "73",
        "cdp_length_Max": "73"
    }
}]
```

Comment: See http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-Options-66 and http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-readeia608

Comment: Thank you Gyan, I tried with `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "abc.mxf[out+subcc]" -map 0:v -c:s copy output.scc` but I am getting "No such filter: 'abc.mxf'". Can you please help me identify issue with this command? Thank you.